# SSH login using public key failed

Tags: ssh, localhost, rsa

On localhost running sshd service. Created two pairs of rsa keys for `root` and `user1` using ssh-keygen. Copied from root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub to user1/.ssh/id_rsa.pub. Changed permissions to 600. Tried `ssh -l user1 localhost` and `ssh -l root localhost` but both failed with *Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).*. Do I have to copy public key to `~/.ssh` folder for both users? What is wrong with configuration? Why I cannot connect to localhost?

File `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
UsePAM no
AllowUsers user1 root
PermitRootLogin yes
```

In file `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` is uncommented lines:

```
   RSAAuthentication yes
   PasswordAuthentication no
   ForwardX11 no
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
   PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

---

EDIT 1

I am trying to connect to localhost. I have to be able to login to user1 using only public key while possible to login as root with public key and/or password.

---

EDIT 2

I copied `cp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub /home/user1/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Changed permissions `chmod -R 700 ~/.ssh` and `chmod -R 700 /home/user1/.ssh`. Restarted sshd 'service ssh restart'. But it seems not working.

---

EDIT 4

```
root@ubuntu:~# ssh-copy-id user1@localhost
The authenticity of host 'localhost (127.0.0.1)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 34:29:b6:1b:fe:84:eb:82:85:77:87:f6:25:39:61:5a.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'localhost' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).

root@ubuntu:~# ssh-copy-id root@localhost
Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
```

Log:

```
# tail /var/log/auth.log

... ubuntu sshd[8476]: User root not allowed because account is locked
```

A good SSH troubleshot article: [Problems and Solutions](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/ssh/ch12_02.htm#ch12-54149.html)

Comment: Are you trying to ssh to localhost? Why? Did you get password prompt?

Comment: Have you looked at the server's sshd logs?

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this issue when i tried to login to an account that has no password, even though i use SSH key pair authentication and have password login turned off. The solution was to set a password using my root account:

```
passwd user1
Enter new UNIX password:
Retype new UNIX password:
passwd: password updated successfully
```

Comment: In your case, this would have been a PAM accounting issue. `UsePAM no`  is present in this configuration and it would not be applicable.

Comment: Andrew B, that's not true. I'm having the same problem: I cannot log in when I set "UsePAM no" when the user in question doesn't have a password. Once I set a password, the login works fine.

Answer (score 4):

1. Whenever encountering a problem ssh'ing to a server,  it's always best to add the `-v` flag, e.g.

   ```
   $ ssh -v host -l user
   ```
2. In both above cases, the public key (`id_rsa.pub`) should be added to the "remote user's .ssh/authorized_keys" file.  In your case above,  both to root and user1.  This can easily be done via the [ssh-copy-id](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-copy-id) command.
3. `/var/log/secure` will hold clues as to why the login was not successful.
4. Directory permissions should be 700 [rwx] (not 600) [rw-]

Comment: ssh-copy-id is not working because ssh connection cannot be established. Tried to simply copy public key of user1 to root nevertheless authorization failed. Where should be public key of user1 copied if I need to connect to local host?

Comment: From the log snippet above,  appears that the root user is locked, ie in /etc/shadow, there is '!!' in the password file.  Give the root user a password - this should unlock the root account.  If you'd like user1 to be able to ssh into the system as 'root', add user1 'id_rsa.pub' key to /root/.ssh/authorized_keys.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue a while back try doing a

```
chmod -R 600 ~/.ssh
```

Apparently if the file permissions are right but the directory permissions are not the same kind of permissions error can crop up.

I also think that you need to rename the file from id_rsa.pub to authorized_keys.

Comment: On Debian-6+squeeze3, you will definitely need permission 700

Answer (score 1):

Some notes:
Since you have specifically disabled the password authentication, you cannot login with password. I believe that you have to configure the permitted users with some other (Match User is possibly the best way to move forward).
Also, you need to specifically allow root user (PermitRootLogin set it to yes).

Answer (score 1):

It would make sense to give us some more information about the settings in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, in particular `StrictModes` (`grep StrictModes /etc/ssh/sshd_config`). `StrictModes` is the setting that governs how sensitive `sshd` reacts to the file and folder permissions of each user's respective `~/.ssh` and `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.
You also didn't give us the setting of `AuthorizedKeysFile` in your `sshd_config`. Very much relevant, if your SSH server is looking for the file somewhere else than you put it.

But aside from the answers so far, there can be a multitude of reasons for this. The problem is that even though you tried, there is not enough information to make a sure guess what's wrong.

One more thing can be PAM restrictions (`UsePAM` in `sshd_config`). Ubuntu used to have that at some point. If the user account didn't have a password set (public key only authentication) it wouldn't be allowed in.

But let me give you a generic method to debug such issues.

### Generic troubleshooting of `sshd`

What I find generally very useful in any such cases is to start `sshd` without letting it daemonize ("go into background and detach from the terminal"). Often the logs won't be overly helpful, in particular when you have a configuration error (which isn't the obvious case at least).

You start it from the terminal like that:

```
# $(which sshd) -Ddp 10222
```

This will give you plenty of debug output that would otherwise not appear (without the `-d`) or end up in the logs if you're lucky.

**NB:** the `$(which sshd)` is the best method to satisfy `sshd` requirement of an absolute path. Otherwise you'll get the following error: `sshd re-exec requires execution with an absolute path`. The `-p 10222` makes `sshd` listen on that alternative port, overriding the configuration file - this is so that it doesn't clash with potentially running `sshd` instances. *Make sure to choose a free port here.*

This method has helped me many many times in finding issues, be it authentication issues, performance issues or other types of issues. To get really verbose output to `stdout`, use `$(which sshd) -Ddddp 10222` (note the added `dd` to increase verbosity). For more debugging goodness check `man sshd`.

On the client side `ssh` can take `-v` (up to `-vvv`) to be really verbose about what it is doing.

---

The log line

```
... ubuntu sshd[8476]: User root not allowed because account is locked
```

hints at that being the problem, so run:

```
sudo passwd -u root
```

Answer (score 1):

On CentOS, selinux can block authentication. To solve the problem using the command:

```
restorecon -Rv ~ /. ssh
```