# LDAP connection seems to keep failing

Tags: openldap

What configuration errors would lead to the situation where ldapsearch works and getent works, but authentication seems to fail sometimes during SSH login?

I have two servers that query a third server for LDAP authentication. All servers are running Ubuntu 18.04.

The LDAP server (running OpenLDAP / slapd) uses a self-signed certificate and both client servers have "TLS_REQCERT allow" in /etc/ldap/ldap.conf .
 Both client servers can also successfully use ldapsearch over ldaps to query for users. On both client servers, I can run getent passwd and get the expected results.

However, on one server, when I log in via ssh, I experience a consistent delay (about thirty seconds). /var/log/auth.log from that server includes these lines:

```
pam_systemd(sshd:session): Failed to create session: Connection timed out  
nss_ldap: reconnecting to LDAP server...
nss_ldap: reconnected to LDAP server ldaps://[IP address] after 1 attempt
systemd-logind: nss_ldap: could not connect to any LDAP server as [...] - Can't contact LDAP server
systemd-logind: nss_ldap: failed to bind to LDAP server ldaps://[IP address]: Can't contact LDAP server
```

As far as know, all relevant pieces of the configuration for the two client servers are the same as each other's.

I have tried:

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind
sudo systemctl restart polkit
```

sudo journalctl -u systemd-logind shows:

```
nss_ldap: could not connect to any LDAP server as [...] - Can't contact 
nss_ldap: failed to bind to LDAP server ldaps://[IP address]: Can't contact LDAP server
nss_ldap: reconnecting to LDAP server (sleeping 1 seconds)...
```

On the client side of SSH, I see what's outlined here: [ssh connection takes forever to initiate, stuck at "pledge: network"](https://serverfault.com/questions/792486/ssh-connection-takes-forever-to-initiate-stuck-at-pledge-network)

Comment: Jerry's fix works.
Follow debian documentation : https://wiki.debian.org/fr/LDAP/NSS

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that "apt install libnss-ldapd" seems to fix the problem, which removes libnss-ldap and installs nscd and nslcd.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure what worked for me:

```
apt install libnss-ldapd
service nscd stop
```

or changing from ldapi:// to ldap://

My REHL7 server (running openladp) is configured for ldapi:// and it has RHEL7 clients connecting through ldapi://

I couldn't get the Debian 11 instance to use ldapi:// though.

EDIT: Using ldap:// instead of ldapi:// worked for me.

Comment: Ran another VM to test. Did not install libnss-ldapd but DID use ldap:// instead of ldapi://. It worked without any issues.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
apt install libnss-ldapd
systemctl restart systemd-logind
```

fixed it for me