# Handling ssh brute force attacks from ::1?

Tags: ubuntu, brute-force-attacks

I have an Ubuntu server; first I ran into this, as I couldn't log in via ssh at all:

[ssh connection takes forever to initiate, stuck at "pledge: network"](https://serverfault.com/questions/792486/ssh-connection-takes-forever-to-initiate-stuck-at-pledge-network)

After a hard reboot, I could log in - but everything executes extremely slow on the server - even if `top` said there is only about 1% CPU utilization.

When I tried to do update, it got to here:

```
$ sudo apt update

Hit:1 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
```

... and now it is stuck, still waiting for the command to complete.

I managed to run:

```
$ grep Failed /var/log/auth.log
...
Apr 23 10:54:14 myserv sshd[1994]: Failed password for root from ::1 port 50182 ssh2
Apr 23 10:54:14 myserv sshd[1992]: Failed password for invalid user pt from ::1 port 50180 ssh2
```

... so clearly something is trying to brute-force into ssh.

Basically, I would have tried to use `fail2ban` - however, the IP address reported is `::1`, which as I can see, is usually whitelisted in `fail2ban`.

Is it possible to inspect where are these attempts coming from - and possibly mitigate them via fail2ban (or something similar)?

Comment: There's no place like `::1`. The login attempts are coming from your localhost, so they are already in somehow.

Comment: I never allow port 22 or even 2222 to be used for SSH and only allows specific users with strong passwords. I know that's not much comfort now, but if you resolve it consider a different & random port, allow specific users and even lock it down to IP addresses if possible. I think @EsaJokinen is correct, either they are in already or have been in and deployed code.

Comment: There is more evidence of a brute force (or any) attack. The problem likely lies elsewhere. DNS? Firewall?  What is the contents if /etc/resolved.conf?  What dies ping www.google.com return?

Comment: Thanks for that, all - was not aware `::1` refers to localhost; looks like I've had a port forward of port 22 enabled somewhere ... thankfully there is no critical data on that server, so I'll try to reinstall it eventually.

Comment: This is quite unusual and I would bet on a port forwarding too (your router maybe). Makes no sense to brute force SSH when you are already inside the machine.

Comment: I had a similar issue. My `::1` login attempts was because I was accessing my SSH server through an SSH reverse tunnel to bypass a CGNAT.

Answer (score 0):

`::1` is the loopback address in IPv6. The equivalent of `127.0.0.1` for IPv4.

Your server cannot brute-fore itself. If your server has been compromised, you should completely reinstall it.

As a general recommendation, try to use a different than default SSH port.